# Class not registered in IntelliJ IDEA ultimate 9.0 version

Tags: java, intellij-idea

I am new to IntelliJ IDEA IDE. I am using 9.0.2 version, when i am trying to run a jsp page class not registered error occurs.Please give me your valuable suggestions.

Best Regards

Answer (score 0):

Usually you don't need to run "jsp page class". Jsp page become converted to java to become interpreted in pair with servlet (if exists) or standalone (if you have only jsp). Moreover they should be run in `Tomcat` or other Servlet container. Probably this is the reason that IDEA don't allow to run it standalone.

At first take a look to servlet/jsp sample [here](http://met.guc.edu.eg/OnlineTutorials/JSP%20-%20Servlets/A%20servlet%20example.aspx)

Or an example with IDEA [here](http://wiki.jetbrains.net/intellij/Creating_a_simple_Web_application_and_deploying_it_to_Tomcat)